# Sending HTML and format it in the email

Tags: php, html, email

Im creatingan online shop and i want to send an email receipt... I've gotten raw html to be sent to the correct email address using the php mail() function but thats all it is raw html... Is there a way that the email client (gmail) will see this as a web layout

At the moment it looks like this when the email client receives it

```
<HTML><BODY><TABLE class = product cellpadding = 0 cellsspacing = 0 border = 0 width = 
100%><tr><td width = 50 height = 60><a href="shopProcessCart.php?action=delete&id=3" 
class="r"><img src="inc/remove.png" border="0" alt="Remove"></a></td><td>Cape Clear
 History Part 2</td><td width = 70>&euro;14.99</td><td width = 40><input type="number" 
name="qty3" value="1" size="2" maxlength="2" /></td></TABLE><p>Total: 
<strong>&euro;14.99</strong></p></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set the header to html email:

```
    $to = "email@example.com"; 
    $from = "email2@example.com"; 
    $subject = "Hello! This is HTML email"; 

    //begin of HTML message 
    $message = <<<EOF 
<html> 
  <body bgcolor="#DDDDDD"> 
    YOUR HTML EMAIL
  </body> 
</html> 
EOF; 
   //end of message 
    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set html headers

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

And pass it as a parameter in php's mail() function

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);